# pandas data frame, max of columns while keeping index

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

As output I want a dataframe with only 1 row (index should be the last date) and the maximum value by column.

```
                A        B         C
2000-06-13 35.44110000 34.17990000 34.02230000
2000-06-14 92.11310000 91.05430000 90.95720000
2000-06-15 57.97080000 57.78140000 58.19820000
2000-06-16 34.17050000 92.45300000 58.51070000
```

I know I can use `df.tails(n).max()` but that turns the entire thing into a Series which seems rather complicated to get back into a data frame.

Does anyone know something elegant or functional to accomplish it?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(df.tails(n).max())`? (I'm not sure why you need the `tails(n)` here, as it sselects the last n rows in the dataframe, but you suggested it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want `idxmax`?

```
df.idxmax().to_frame().T
```

Output

```
            A           B           C
0  2000-06-14  2000-06-16  2000-06-14
```

---

Or, per comments below.

```
df.max().to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
         A       B        C
0  92.1131  92.453  90.9572
```

And,

```
df.max().to_frame().T.rename(index={0:df.idxmax().max()})
```

Output:

```
                  A       B        C
2000-06-16  92.1131  92.453  90.9572
```

Comment: No I want the maximum values of the columns in a single row with the index value of the last date

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
df = df[df['column'] == df['column'].max()]
```

The resulting dataframe will have the index saved as well as all the column values...